# Declaring global variable using local variable

Tags: ocaml

Let's say I want to declare a global variable using local variable :
I can do (1)

```
let y = let x = 1 in x + 1;;
```

But now if I do (2)

```
let x = 1 in let y = x + 1;;
```

It seems ocaml doesn't understand this syntax, it stops at ;;, but I don't see why, because (3)

```
let x = 1 in 1;;
```

works, even if it's useless.

What happens at (2) ? How is ocaml trying to analyze this expression ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The big difference between the two types of `let`s is that `let ... in ...` is an expression, but `let` without `in` is not. Now the part after `in` in `let ... in ...` must be an expression, so the `in`less `let` is not allowed there - it's only allowed at the top-level of a module.